# Difference between winforms, web forms, and windows forms

Tags: windows, winforms, forms

Right now I am working on c# windows applications developement. But my concern is I want to know what is the difference between winforms in c# .

what is the difference between winforms and windows forms in c#?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Winforms and Windows Forms are the same thing.  Winforms is the shortened name for Windows Forms.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms):

> Windows Forms (WinForms) is the name given to the graphical
>   application programming interface (API) included as a part of
>   Microsoft .NET Framework

Additional info from [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsapplications/thread/74b519f3-1173-4095-b4b7-e37dbd5b6bd3/) answer:

> Based on my understanding, you want to know the difference between
>   Windows based application and WinForms application development using
>   c#.  Windows based application is that the application is
>   developed under Window Operating System, excluding such application
>   developed under other Operating System like Linux & Unix.
>
> However,there are two kinds of windows based application in .net, WinForm &
>   Web application. you can develop several different kinds of
>   Windows-based applications. You can create Windows Forms and Windows
>   service applications that leverage the power of the .NET Framework, or
>   you can use Visual C++ to create Windows Win32-based applications
>
> However, the WinForm application is a kind of managed application,
>   develop on .Net platform. It's the extension of the Windows-based
>   application. The Windows Forms classes contained in the .NET Framework
>   are designed to be used for GUI development. You can easily create
>   command windows, buttons, menus, toolbars, and other screen elements
>   with the flexibility necessary to accommodate shifting business needs.
>   The topics in this section provide details about how to use the
>   features offered by Windows Forms.